# How to replace a repeated char with some characters or string

Tags: java

I need to replace a repeated char with `$%` followed by the char followed by `$%`.

e.g. "HELLO" will become "HE$%L$%O"

The following code that I wrote gives "HE$%L$%LO".

Please guide

```
    int index=0;
    String str1="";
    String str2="";
    String str4="";
    String str5="";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {

        char ch=str.charAt(i);
        index=str.indexOf(ch);
        if(index!=i) {

            str4="$%"+str.charAt(index)+ "$%";
            str1=str.charAt(index)+str5;

            str2=str.replaceFirst(str1,str4);

        }
    }
    return str2;
```

Comment: - Start by replacing '@#' in your code by '$%'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's code missing because i can't see the duplicate character check, but what you want to do is go through str5 before you concat it and strip off all of the duplicate characters that are at the beginning. Then concat to your String.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution: Id solves the case if duplicates are more than 2 too. So remove all duplicates:

```
public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String result = replace("HELLO");
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }

    private static String replace(String data) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length();) {
            int j = i + 1;
            while (j < data.length() && data.charAt(i) == data.charAt(j)) {
                j++;
            }
            if(j > i + 1) { // exist duplicate
                stringBuilder.append("$%").append(data.charAt(i)).append("$%");
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(data.charAt(i));
            }
            i = j;
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
result = HE$%L$%O
```